# Select a Row with Max of CreatedOn group by a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    Container, CreatedOn, * 
from 
    Inventory_container 
where 
    container in (select IC.Container
                  from INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC
                  inner join CONTAINER C on IC.Container = C.Container
                  where C.ContainerClassID = '100000011' 
                  group by IC.Container
                  having count(IC.Container) >= 2)
```

Below is the Result of the Query:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueMOO.png]

As you can see there are similar containers with 2 rows
I want to select the row with the latest createdon.

Please help editing my query.

Comment: Which Database?

Comment: share your source table data and it is better to provide text data than image

Comment: Microsoft SQL is the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think a sub-query and join  would help  you

```
 select iC.* from INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC inner join
         inner join
         (
          select IC.Container,max(IC.CreatedOn) as CreatedOn
          from INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC
          inner join CONTAINER C on IC.Container = C.Container
          where C.ContainerClassID = '100000011' 
          group by IC.Container
          having count(IC.Container) >= 2
          ) t on IC.Container=t.Container and IC.CreatedOn=t.CreatedOn
```

Comment: Works !!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server try below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
       SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Container ORDER BY CreatedOn) AS RowNo
       FROM INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC INNER JOIN CONTAINER C ON 
       IC.Container=C.Container
       WHERE C.ContainerClassID='100000011' 
       GROUP BY IC.Container,CreatedOn
       HAVING COUNT(IC.Container)>=2
     ) AS T
WHERE RowNo = 1
```

Comment: its giving error .it says  " Column inventory_container.Inventoryid is invalid in the select list beause it is not contained in any aggregate function or the group by clause.. "  and " the column "Container " was specified multiple times for  'T' "

Comment: its microsoft sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to write one more subquery to your query.

```
select 
   Container,CreatedOn, * 
from 
    Inventory_container 
where 
    container in (select IC.Container
                  from INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC
                  inner join CONTAINER C on IC.Container = C.Container
                  where C.ContainerClassID = '100000011' 
                  and IC.CreatedOn= 
                  (select max(IC1.CreatedOn) from INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC1
                   where IC1.container=IC.container));
                  group by IC.Container
                  having count(IC.Container) >= 2 ;
```

I am assuming that the query which you have mentioned is syntactically correct as per your DB design.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query-:

```
With CTE as
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Container ORDER BY CreatedOn desc) AS RN
       FROM INVENTORY_CONTAINER IC INNER JOIN CONTAINER C ON 
       IC.Container=C.Container
       WHERE C.ContainerClassID='100000011' 
       GROUP BY IC.Container
       HAVING COUNT(IC.Container)>=2
)select * from CTE where RN=1
```

SQL Server